# Gravitational lens to illuminate a planet?

Tags: cosmology, gravitational-lensing

I've been involved in a Internet debate:

**Is it possible to have a  special cosmic configuration consisted of multiple bodies such that a planet's surface can be lit up by light focused by gravitational lens effect caused by some giant mass bodies inside the system?**

Somebody say it is a silly idea because they think even such configuration exist it certainly won't last long before the huge mass bodies drags the planet into themselves and the stable system can never be correctly set up by all means.

I am not a physics major myself. I wonder if anyone can clarify the matter using mathematical terms here.

(Source: http://jandan.net/2014/08/01/remote-lens-galaxy.html in Chinese)

Comment: If you ignore what's likely to occur naturally, you can have arbitrarily strong lensing from arbitrarily low-mass objects.  You could crunch a small moon into a black hole and then use it as a tiny lens.  You question is still pretty imprecise though because you don't describe the light source or what you mean by "lit up" or what you mean by "focused".  Gravitational lensing tends to make a focus line, not a focus point.

Comment: "Planet's surface can be lit up" - obviously, it can be illuminated even without lensing and lensing can for sure heighten the intensity of illumination of the planet. "Giant mass bodies inside the system" - inside which system? The system of a star and a planet? There might be a slight language barrier here, so maybe try describing the problem from different angles so we can better answer your question.

Comment: Oh I am sorry for my wording. By using "lit up", I was thinking "the surface get burned like ants under convex lens", say the evaporation point of materials on the surface of the planet under its environment is 373K. The "Giant mass bodies inside the system" is referred to the "lens" that bends light onto a planet's surface,it could be black holes or galaxies. The light source, the lens, and the planet consist the "system".

Comment: People in the debate said such balance won't exist theoretically because the "lens" satisfying the "focusing the light onto the surface of the planet to burn up objects" requirement will either drag the target planet into themselves (lens being too close to the target planet) or prevent the light escaping from its field  (lens being too able to deflect lights). They don't take consider of the masses of the light sources as they think if lens itself can destroy the balance between the lens and the planet then it is sufficient to prove the system is theoretically unable to set up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the way the Earth is illuminated by the Sun:

[image: Illumination by Sun]

Light travels in straight lines, so on the Earth we only get the light that happens to be travelling in our direction, and of course this is a tiny fraction of all the light emitted by the Sun.

Now suppose we could place a gigantic lens in between the Sun and the Earth to focus the Sun's light onto the Earth:

[image: Lens]

The lens captures more of the Sun's light than the Earth does, because it's closer to the Sun and bigger than the Earth. So if it focusses all this light onto the Earth then the brightness of the Sun's light on the Earth is going to be much greater than normal. So it will increase the illumination of the Earth - I'm guessing that this is what you mean by illuminating a planet.

This works because the angle $\alpha$ subtended by the lens is much greater than the angle subtended by the Earth. This allows the lens to capture lots of light and focus all that light on the Earth.

But we couldn't create a gravitational lens that big in the Solar System bcause the mass needed would be vastly greater than the mass of the Sun and all the planets combined. Even the Sun, which is by far the heaviest object in the Solar system can only deflect light by about 0.0005° i.e. the angle $\alpha$ in the diagram above would only be 0.0005°. This is about a factor of 5 less than the angle subtended by the Earth, so such a lens would increase the illumination of the Earth by only a small amount.

And this is the problem with your plan for illuminating a planet. You need lenses capable of capturing light over a wide angle $\alpha$, but any lens that would fit in between the Sun and the planet wouldn't capture enough light to make much difference. There are much bigger lenses, like galaxy clusters, but they're millions of light years away so they aren't much use.